# Submitting a form using a wildcard selector using serialize?

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I am having trouble submitting input information using a wildcard selector with serialize. In my form I have set the name attributes.

So is my problem because I have input ,selects and hidden fields?

My code is below:

```
$('[id^=editeventform_]').submit(function(){
    var evtn_edit_form_id_data = $(this).attr("id");

    var event_date_edit = $("#event_date_edit", this).val();
    var event_orig_name_edit = $("#event_orig_name_edit", this).val();
    var event_orig_tel_edit = $("#event_orig_tel_edit", this).val();
    var event_orig_email_edit = $("#event_orig_email_edit", this).val();

    if (event_title_edit == "") {
      $("#event_title_edit", this).focus();
      $("#event_title_edit", this).val("");
      $("#event_title_edit", this).css({background:"#b72a18", color:"#fff"});
      return false;
    }
    if (event_date_edit == "") {
      $("#event_date_edit", this).focus();
      $("#event_date_edit", this).val("");
      $("#event_date_edit", this).css({background:"#b72a18", color:"#fff"});
      return false;
    }

    $(this).html('<center><img src="/images/ajax-loader-cater.gif"></center>');

    var dataString = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/process.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
                $(this).html('<p>Thank you your event has successfully been edited.</p>');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(window.location).attr('href', '/members/catering-activity.php');
            }, 3500);
        }
 });
return false;
});
```

When submitting the form the alert "dataString" returns no information?

I am a beginner when it comes to Jquery and can't find what the issue is with my code and why it won't return any input values.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some tests and came to the following:

1. You don't have posted your html but i guess your input fields miss the name attribute:

   `<input id="event_date_edit" name="foobar" type="text" />`
2. You need to add `e.preventDefault();` in your submit function to prevent the browser from reloading the page:

   `$('[id^=editeventform_]').submit(function(e){ 
       e.preventDefault();
       //...`
3. As far as i see, you don't have defined the variable `event_title_edit`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks fro your suggestion, this doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you post a log of the `dataString` variable right before you submit the ajax post. Use: `console.log(dataString);` and look at the firebug console window.

Comment: @WayNe - I get and error in the console (an empty string)